# Difference between align-items & text-align in internal CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I didn't understand what's the difference between these properties  of css.. please anybody explain  it..

Comment: we cannot really talk about difference since they are completely different and not related at all

Answer (score 1):

following is the Difference between these two properties.
**Text-align**
The text-align property is used to specify the horizontal alignment of inline-level content such as text and images.
**Align-items**
The align-items property defines the default behavior for how items are laid out along the cross axis (perpendicular to the main axis)

Comment: Thanks abdullah for this

Answer (score 1):

```
text-align - specifies the horizontal alignment of text in an element.
align-items - specifies the default alignment for items inside the flexible container.
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS **`align-items`** property sets the align-self value on all direct children as a group. In Flexbox, it controls the alignment of items on the Cross Axis. In Grid Layout, it controls the alignment of items on the Block Axis within their grid area.

The **`text-align`** CSS property sets the horizontal alignment of a block element or table-cell box. This means it works like vertical-align but in the horizontal direction.

For more information use https://developer.mozilla.org/

Answer (score -1):

[`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) is used for positioning elements in a flex-box, where [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) is used to position text at the left, center or right part of an element or justify it to fill it (like you see in newspapers).